# How to GET image from url via API in java?

Tags: java

This should be an easy learning task but something went wrong:

> Use API request to get image from some link and check it is in Base64 standard.

```
private static void getRequest() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("http://apimeme.com/meme?meme=Alarm-Clock&top=Top+text&bottom=Bottom+text");
    
    InputStream is = (InputStream) url.openStream();
    FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(is.toString());
    byte imageData[] = new byte[2048];
    imageInFile.read(imageData);
    System.out.println(isBase64(imageInFile.toString()));
}

static boolean isBase64(String path) {
    try {
        Base64.getDecoder().decode(path);
        return true;
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Right now problem is on line

```
InputStream is = (InputStream) url.openStream();
```

Server sends 403. How to fix this? Method `isBase64` should work but the program doesn't reach this line.

Comment: @Abra that was my first instinct, but I doubt you randomly find an URL pointung to an image that is decoded in base64

Comment: The sever sent you 403 because your code is not authorized to access the resource. Please refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) to know more about the 403 error code. You may have to use some authentication mechanism if the resource is secured.

Comment: @SanjuThomas: read my answer. 403 in HTTP means that you do not get access by any authorization either. If authentication yourself would help, the server would send a 401 instead. (This is unless the server does not honor HTTP standards entirely)

Comment: @johannes-h, you are right.

Comment: @Abra this link was in task so first of all code must work with it... if it will work with other code - it will be good, but link from task is priority

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your need 3 header for avoid http 403 error code

```java
private static void getRequest() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("http://apimeme.com/meme?meme=Alarm-Clock&top=Top+text&bottom=Bottom+text");
    URLConnection is = url.openConnection();
    is.setRequestProperty("Host", "apimeme.com");
    is.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "*");
    is.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "*");

    byte[] imageData = new byte[2048];
    File downloadFile = new File("download.png");
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(downloadFile);
    int read;
    while ((read = is.getInputStream().read(imageData)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(imageData, 0, read);
    }
    outputStream.close();
    System.out.println(isBase64(downloadFile.getAbsolutePath()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

403 is means that you do not have permission to view this URL. You cannot do anything  to fix this client side, even authorization would not help (if the ressource required authorization, the  server would send 401 instead). So to fix the issue, whoever is in charge of the web server delivering the URL you're trying to access will have to fix this - if  they think you should have access.

Comment: The thing is: if you open the url in a browser, you get a http 200. So it might be request headers etc

Comment: I get an 200 OK with curl (no additional header sent) as well. So it must be @Ra'UkoLord being blocked from that ressource.

Comment: this is actually weird because i see this... http://prntscr.com/1259c1l

thought i need to analyse this pic (it was in task)

Comment: If you can access it in your browser, you should not get a 401 in Java. If you do, this is actually pretty weird and might be way more complex. Either way, your code looks ok and should not cause this.

Comment: if i change link to some other i have different error: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@26f67b76 (The system cannot find the file specified. or  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream cannot be cast to org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream. what is wrong?

Comment: The FileNotFound exception is thrown if the file (or URI) does not exist. The ClastCastException however I can't explain by your code. Did you accidentally mess up your imports and import the incorrect InputStream class?